# justify-content: space-around doesn't work when targeting an element nested inside a class

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

This code works:

```
aside {
  /* Your styles for the aside element */
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #2800da;
}

i.fa {
  /* Styles for the icons */
  font-size: 0.9em;
}



  <aside >
          <i className="fa fa-bars"></i>
          <i className="fa fa-home"></i>
          <i className="fa fa-search"></i>
          <i className="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
          <i className="fa fa-user"></i>
          <i className="fa fa-spotify"></i>
          <i className="fa fa-cog"></i>
          <i className="fa fa-soundcloud"></i>
        </aside>
```

This is the result:
[image]

Here everything seems to work except for `justify-content: space-around`:

```
.LeftNavBar {
  aside {
    /* Your styles for the aside element */
    flex: 0 0 40px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around !important;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #ff0000;

    i.fa {
      /* Styles for the icons */
      font-size: 0.9em;
    }
  }
}

 <div className="LeftNavBar">
        <aside >
          <i className="fa fa-bars"></i>
          <i className="fa fa-home"></i>
          <i className="fa fa-search"></i>
          <i className="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
          <i className="fa fa-user"></i>
          <i className="fa fa-spotify"></i>
          <i className="fa fa-cog"></i>
          <i className="fa fa-soundcloud"></i>
        </aside>
    </div>
```

This is the result:
[image]

No idea why. In the debugger, checking or unchecking `justify-content: space-around;` doesn't have any effect. While the other properties get applied and unapplied accordingly.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I believe this is to do with the height of the container (`space-around` does not affect that and will not add space between elements, it just arranges the existing space). Try setting the display of the `LeftNavBar` element to `flex`.

Comment: The `justify-content` property distributes free space in the container. If you don't set a height on the container that exceeds the height of the content, there's no free space to distribute.

Comment: Aren't the two examples essentially the same. In the beginning I'm targeting aside directly and in the second I'm targeting inside the class LeftNavBar? So why does it work in the first example and in the second it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

*justify-content* doesn't work when there isn't enough space for the element to move around. Try setting and increasing the height/padding of the div to see if the *justify-content* can finally apply.

Comment: Aren't the two examples essentially the same. In the beginning I'm targeting aside directly and in the second I'm targeting inside the class LeftNavBar? So why does it work in the first example and in the second it doesn't

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe it has to do with the fact that the height property is not necessarily inherited from a parent element. Try setting the height of aside to inherit in the second example and see if it becomes like the first example.